# See pull requests previously created and merged by me in visual studio online

Tags: git, visual-studio

We use git as our source control. We create pull requests in visual studio online. Is there anyway to see all the previous pull requests I have made(they are already merged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If you are using visual studio online. This can get you to the previously merged Pull Requests:
Visual studio online -> pull requests -> right corner Status -> Completed

Can't believe it was that simple!